# How To Not Instance on the Last Control Point on a "Instance on Points" Node?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I can't figure out how to exclude this last point on the spline from the `Selection` of `Instance on Points`. I thought `Factor` was a value between `0` & `1`, but it turns out it isn't when i read the documentation. I'm not quite sure i fully understood the documentation but it seems that `Factor` is the portion length in `meters` to control point so that would mean that `Factor` divided by total `Length` should result in a value within the range of `0` to `1`, am i mistaken? So assuming it was 1 for whole length or even lesser like `0.8` i would expect that a comparison of less than these values would exclude the last point.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

It somehow works now if i use a hard-coded integer value of 3 but if i plug a value that also has a value of 3 inside, it destroys my plant output. I also tried float to integer converter and still doesn't work. Weird bug?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this, using **endpoint selection** node:

[image]

Comment: oh cool can this also exclude the first point? i'll try this out now!

Comment: Yep, of course.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie To be precise, you can also decide to exclude more than one point at the end as well as the start.

Comment: thank you, it does work perfectly if i use a hard coded value of 3. but it doesn't work if you use a value plugged from another node. i checked the value that flows into the node connection and it is still "3" but it behaves differently. must be a bug? can u see the screenshot i attached?

Comment: nevermind. i just used multiply by 0.9 instead of subtract -1. works now. thank you!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Okay, don't know what exactly happens there, I just saw in the screenshot that there goes a dotted line into the _Subtract_ node, which means a field of values instead of a single value - maybe that's why it didn't work. Although I don't understand what makes it work with the _Multiply_ then. But well, as long as it helped...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hey thank you for pointing that one out. yeah that is odd, you're right, it shouldn't be broken lines. i checked it the group input node is only a single value, duno why it shows as broken lines but if you're interested you can see the file here pasteall.org/blend/fae215baf52445e4aefb96a7794ff3b3 maybe you can let me know why that is?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie First of all this just means that there _could_ be a list of values plugged in. You can see it from the black dot in the diamond shaped input. This means, it _can_ operate multiple input data. If the dot is missing, than the input only accepts single data like one value, one vector etc. This is when regarding the unconnected input. A little confusing is that a dotted input when connected can suddenly hide the dot, if the data chain from start to end only uses a single value. I've explained that in an answer with examples a while ago , but can't find it right now.

Comment: ah alright, thank you very much for your help and input much appreciated!